# crossplatform solution for symlink handling with VCS

Tags: version-control, mercurial, symlink

The thing I'm trying to do is to implement version control for huge amount of XSLT files in our system. The problem is, that the way I'm trying to manage XSLT files isn't supported by Windows (that is used by most part of developers as a desktop OS):
Each XSLT is used to transform appropriate customers data and it's location in filesystem is a directory named as customers identifier (like 1234567890123). It makes this structure very human-unreadable. 
 Thats why I made symlinks to each directory with name like "Company Name" and init mercurial repository.
 So, cloning this repository is working alright in Linux, but in Windows i received text files instead of symlinks.

Any usefull advice, how to solve my problem, is welcome. Hope for You, people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Mercurial your choice must be [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) (read also [Subrepositories](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) from "Mercurial Kick Start Exercises" of Aragost) (or GuestRepo as better iteration of idea)

**Why**

Directory of subrepo inside super-repo may have different name, than real basename of subrepo. This way you may have `1234567890123` as directory of subrepo, but .hgsub will show direct relation of `1234567890123` with `Acme Co.

**How**

Define **non-trivial path** for subrepo in .hgsub, like

`1234567890123 = /PATH/TO/ACME`